# url encoding with javascript window open

Tags: javascript, asp.net, urlencode, url-encoding

ASP.NET 4.0, webform site

There is a link in my site is to call another page and pass url parameters, it looks like below.

http://www.foo.com/foo.aspx?anotherURI?param1=aaa&26param2=bbb

However, I need to do url encode for "anotherURI?param1=aaa&26param2=bbb", so it turns into:

http://www.foo.com/foo.aspx?anotherURI?param1%3Daaa%26param2%3Dbbb

Now if I want to enclose this with javascript, it won't work. How do I encode the url again?

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.foo.com/foo.aspx?anotherURI?param1%3Daaa%26param2%3Dbbb', 'popup'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct the URI:

WRONG: http://www.foo.com/foo.aspx?anotherURI?param1%3Daaa%26param2%3Dbbb

RIGHT: http://www.foo.com/foo.aspx?anotherURI=param1%3Daaa%26param2%3Dbbb

Example for multiple URIs: http://www.foo.com/foo.aspc?uri1=[encodedURI]&uri2=[encodedURI2]

To get a value from a queryString variable on asp.net:

```
Dim sUrl1 as String = request("VarName")
Dim sUrl2 as String = request("VarName")
Dim sUrl3 as String = request("VarName")
```

If you want to get the decoded URL from that variable:

```
Dim sDecodedUrl1 as String = Server.UrlDecode(sUrl1)
Dim sDecodedUrl2 as String = Server.UrlDecode(sUrl2)
Dim sDecodedUrl3 as String = Server.UrlDecode(sUrl3)
```

Comment: However, param1 & param2 is for another URI. How does that work?

Comment: @Stan in `foo.aspx` page read the value of `Request.QueryString["anotherURI"]` - it will contain raw value like `param1=aaa&26param2=bbb` so you'll need to parse it yourself using Split. If you need further help and Flavio won't be available let me know and I'll pull quick example.

Comment: Sorry if i didn't complete the explaination to this level, letme exemplify:

to get a encoded value from a queryString variable on asp.net:

Comment: Yes this works, you just have to encode the url before setting it to a variable value...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to encode/decode it (the way php does it) use

```
function url_encode(str) {
    str = (str + '').toString();
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28'). replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/%20/g, '+');
}

function url_decode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent((str + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```